# How to display custom field into admin order view page?

Tags: magento2, custom-field, sales-order-view

I created `reward_point` in the `sales_order` table, whenever someone purchased a few points stored in that field.

Now I need to display that point into the admin order view page, I already override `sales_order_view` and create the block, but failed to get the value of the reward point in view page.

sales_order_view.xml

```
  <referenceContainer name="order_additional_info">
      <block class="SimpleMagento\RewardPoint\Block\Sales\Order\ShowReward" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
  </referenceContainer>
```

ShowReward.php

```
class ShowReward extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals
{
   public function _initTotals(){

    $this->_totals['reward_point'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'code' => 'reward_point',
            'strong' => true,
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getReward(),
            'label' => __('Reward Point'),
            'area' => 'footer',
        ]
    );
    return $this;
   }
}
```

for the value of the `reward_point` I have override `Order.php`, which similarly look like:

```
public function getReward()
{
    return $this->getData(OrderInterface::reward_point);
}
```

but for that, I have to override `OrderInterface`, any other way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: please screenshot which position you need to add display..

Comment: @RkRathod, I am trying to add into `total orders` box

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dg8Kf3JQWfGkmM7DahISojb1ZWwqeI8J/view?usp=sharing here is the screenshot of it, Admin>Sales>Order>View>Information tab and Order totals box

Comment: but I am giving more important currently fetch data into block rather than position of my block in frontend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can try below code in your block, it might be helpful to get Reward point custom field value.

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
) {
   $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function getReward()
{
   $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
   $order =  $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
   return $order->getRewardPoint(); // your reward point
}
```

Comment: Thanks I just did that :)

Comment: if possible can you please let me how can I place my block below `Total Orders` box

Answer (score 0):

Other way is

```
protected $factory;

public function __construct(Context $context,
                            OrderFactory $factory,
                            array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

public function getReward(){
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $getOrder = $this->factory->create()->load($id);
    return $getOrder['reward_point'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
) {
$this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function getReward()
{
$order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
$order =  $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
return $order->getRewardPoint(); // your reward point
}